# Once a document gets to a specific size, archive and create another using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

When entering data into a .txt to act as a log, it does get quite large, several MB, and the generic txt reader for MS will have a conniption. Is there a way to put a log into a folder that may or may not exist? So in other words, if a folder doesn't exist, create folder, and cut and paste old log into new folder?

Since I know there will be possibilities for multiple logs to be in said log folder, would there be a way to make it so that there is today's date attached to the log name as well?

Think I solved it...

```
If FileLen(sLogFileName) > 3145728# Then
    sLogFileName = "Open Order Log - " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
    Name sLogFileName As "ThisWorkbook.path & Application.PathSeparator & \Temp\Open Order Log - " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
End If
```

Comment: `1` Several MB should not be a problem for a log file. MS can easily handle it :) `2` if you still want to create separate log files, you can do that as well. What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: Logs are normally helpful for recent activity such as session debugging. If you really need the data then perhaps a database is a better solution. Perhaps other options include date the log filename or even clear after certain timelimit.

Comment: @ooo the reason I have a log is because an excel sheet we have has data in it, that if deleted or changed without knowledge will cost this company hundreds to thousands in a single sale.  So for us it's a CYA.

Comment: @SiddharthRout I am looking online for how to do this, just to get an idea of where to start, I don't even know how to use excel to recognize the physical size of a document outside of itself.

Comment: I think my answer below covers every aspect of your query. If you feel that I missed something, do let me know and I will add that as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your other question, it is obvious that you know how to create a log file.

And from your above question, I could summarize that this is your query

1. Check if a folder exists or not
2. Creating a Folder
3. Add Date to a log file's name
4. Checking the file Size
5. Moving a File

So let's take them one by one.

Check if a folder exists or not. You can use the `DIR` function to check for that. See example below

```
Public Function DoesFolderExist(strFullPath As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo Whoa
    If Not Dir(strFullPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then _
    DoesFolderExist = True
Whoa:
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Regarding your next query, you can use `MKDIR` to create a folder. See this example

```
Sub Sample()
    MkDir "C:\Sample"
End Sub
```

Regarding the third query, you can create a log file with a date appended to it like this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim FlName As String

    FlName = "Sample File - " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")

    Debug.Print FlName
End Sub
```

To check for a file size, you can use the `FileLen` function. See this example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim FileNM As String

    FileNM = "C:\Sample.txt"
    Debug.Print "The File size of " & FileNM & " is " & _
    FileLen(FileNM) & " bytes"
End Sub
```

And to move a file from one directory to the other you can use the `NAME` function. See this example.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim FileNM As String

    FileNM = "C:\Sample.txt"
    Name FileNM As "C:\Temp\Sample.txt"
End Sub
```

So now you can put all of these together to achieve what you want :)

**FOLLOWUP (FROM CHAT)**

This is what we finally arrived at

```
Option Explicit

Dim PreviousValue

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    PreviousValue = Target(1).Value
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim sLogFileName As String, ArchiveFileName As String
    Dim ArchFolder As String, sLogMessage As String
    Dim nFileNum As Long
    Dim NewVal

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    sLogFileName = ThisWorkbook.path & Application.PathSeparator & _
    "Open Order Log.txt"

    If Not Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        If Target.Value <> PreviousValue Then
            '~~> Check if the Log File exists
            If DoesFileFldrExist(sLogFileName) = True Then
                '~~> Check for the File Size
                If FileLen(sLogFileName) > 3145728 Then
                    '~~> Check if the "Log History" folder exists
                    ArchFolder = ThisWorkbook.path & _
                    Application.PathSeparator & "Log History"

                    '~~> If the "Log History" folder doesn't exist, then create it
                    If DoesFileFldrExist(ArchFolder) = False Then
                        MkDir ArchFolder
                    End If

                    '~~> Generate a new file name for the archive file
                    ArchiveFileName = ArchFolder & Application.PathSeparator & _
                    "Open Order Log - " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy") & ".txt"

                    '~~> Move the file
                    Name sLogFileName As ArchiveFileName
                End If
            End If

            '~~> Check if the cell is blank or not
            If Len(Trim(Target.Value)) = 0 Then _
            NewVal = "Blank" Else NewVal = Target.Value

            sLogMessage = Now & Application.UserName & _
            " changed cell " & Target.Address & " from " & _
            PreviousValue & " to " & NewVal

            nFileNum = FreeFile

            '~~> If the log file exists then append to it else create
            '~~> a new output file
            If DoesFileFldrExist(sLogFileName) = True Then
                Open sLogFileName For Append As #nFileNum
            Else
                Open sLogFileName For Output As #nFileNum
            End If

            Print #nFileNum, sLogMessage
            Close #nFileNum
        End If
    End If

LetsContinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub

Public Function DoesFileFldrExist(strFullPath As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo Whoa
    If Not Dir(strFullPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString _
    Then DoesFileFldrExist = True
Whoa:
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: Except, how to move the file after it reaches a specific size... the rest I already had, it was the size requirement issue I was looking at.

Comment: Adding that to the above list :)

Comment: Wouldn't you need to Dim the FileLen?

Comment: No. `FileLen` is not a variable. It is a function.

Comment: Ok, I've been looking at your code, it is good in telling me how large the file is, but I don't see a way to show if the file is a specific size to do an action? Because I really want this to happen in the background without any need to have the end user be notified.

Comment: You Don't need to notify the user. You can use the code like this.. `If FileLen("C:\Sample.txt") > 2000 then` Do your Stuff in the background...

Comment: Thanks, found this `If FileLen(sLogFileName) > 3145728# Then` Going to see if it works.

Comment: Updated OP with first attempt.

Comment: Isn't that the same as what I mentioned in my previous comment? Though you are checking for a different file size...

Comment: I am, like I said I'm always looking for ways, and was since last night. I just got to a computer to comment, I wasn't expecting such a fast response.

Comment: Think I solved it, re-corrected the OP... tell me if you think this will work please?

Comment: Actually it doesn't, I get a compile error: Ambigious name detected: Worksheet_SelectionChange

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16093/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-matt-ridge)

Comment: I noticed something... `Dim PreviousValue ` as what? or is it needed?

Comment: `Dim PreviousValue` is the same as `Dim PreviousValue As Variant` Since we are storing a cell's value in a variable, we don't know what it's type is hence we leave it as variant.

Comment: Ahh ok, got a question, I saw this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12205874/1048319 dealing with a way to record multiple cells at the same time if they are interacted, would it be possible to add the ability to show a record of multiple cells being accessed and changed at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub MoveFiles()
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim MyFile As String
Inlocation = ws.Range("A1").Value & "\"
Lastdate = Format(ws.Range("A3").Value, "DD-MM-YYYY")
Outlocation = ws.Range("A2").Value
Foulocation = Outlocation & "\" & Lastdate
MyFile = Dir(Inlocation & "*.*")

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Check Specified Folder exists or not
If Not oFSO.FolderExists(Foulocation) Then
    'If Folder is available
    MkDir Foulocation
End If

Do Until MyFile = ""
 oFSO.CopyFile Inlocation & MyFile, Foulocation & "\", True
 If Inlocation <> Foulocation Then
 oFSO.DeleteFile Inlocation & MyFile
 End If
 'Name Inlocation & MyFile As Foulocation & "\" & MyFile
 MyFile = Dir
Loop
MsgBox "Files successfully moved to location " & Foulocation

End Sub
```

Comment: It is recommended to provide a brief explanation of what your code is doing.