# I have a code to log usage in an excel sheet, but I get one bug, and one issue

Tags: excel, vba

This is a universal log system, that a few people here and myself have created. I'm rather proud of it... I am running into two issues... if someone can help with the sollution it be great.

Here is the code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim PreviousValue

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim sLogFileName As String, nFileNum As Long, sLogMessage As String

    sLogFileName = ThisWorkbook.path & Application.PathSeparator & "Log.txt"

 On Error Resume Next ' Turn on error handling
    If Target.Value <> PreviousValue Then
        ' Check if we have an error
        If Err.Number = 13 Then
           PreviousValue = 0
        End If
        ' Turn off error handling
        On Error GoTo 0
        sLogMessage = Now & Application.UserName & " changed cell " & Target.Address _
        & " from " & PreviousValue & " to " & Target.Value

        nFileNum = FreeFile                         ' next file number
        Open sLogFileName For Append As #nFileNum   ' create the file if it doesn't exist
        Print #nFileNum, sLogMessage                ' append information
        Close #nFileNum                             ' close the file
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    PreviousValue = Target(1).Value
End Sub
```

Here are the two issues.

1. If more than once cell is selected, and attempted to be written to, the script errors out.
2. If someone edits a cell and leaves it blank, it will show `8/30/2012 1:45:01 PM Matthew Ridge changed cell $K$3 from Test to` instead of `8/30/2012 1:45:01 PM Matthew Ridge changed cell $K$3 from Test to Blank or Empty`

Comment: Target may return a range of cells. As an example you can loop rows in Target using `For Each Row In Target.Rows`. You may also find `If Target.Row = X`, `If Target.Rows.Count = Y` and `If Not Intersect` terms useful (rows/columns interchangeable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matt

Few Things

1. `On Error Resume Next` is not proper handling. It should be avoided unless and until it is absolutely necessary.
2. When you are working with `Worksheet_Change` event, it is better to switch off events and then turn them back on at the end to avoid possible endless loop.
3. If you are switching events off then it is a must that you use proper error handling.
4. Since you are storing the just a single cell in the `PreviousValue` so I am assuming that you do not want the code to run when the user selects multiple cells?

I think this is what you are trying (**UNTESTED**)?

```
Option Explicit

Dim PreviousValue

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim sLogFileName As String, nFileNum As Long, sLogMessage As String
    Dim NewVal

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    sLogFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "Log.txt"

    If Not Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        If Target.Value <> PreviousValue Then
            If Len(Trim(Target.Value)) = 0 Then _
            NewVal = "Blank" Else NewVal = Target.Value

            sLogMessage = Now & Application.UserName & _
            " changed cell " & Target.Address & " from " & _
            PreviousValue & " to " & NewVal

            nFileNum = FreeFile
            Open sLogFileName For Append As #nFileNum
            Print #nFileNum, sLogMessage
            Close #nFileNum
        End If
    End If
LetsContinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    PreviousValue = Target(1).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: I've got no problems using `On Error Resume Next` in the right context. For instance, it's extremely valuable to speed up time critical code.

Comment: `in the right context.` Yup In the right context ;) However the the original code doesn't fall under `right context` Also What happens when the Err.Number is not `13`?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Actually the code is tested, or was when I instituted it a few months ago, and it worked perfectly except my two bugs... hence why I am looking for help. I've added some functionality since then, but not posted because they are incoroprated into a module itself, and not a workbook itself like this one is.

Comment: @MattRidge: `and not a module itself like this one is.` So where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @SiddharthRout The script works without erroring out, my only problem is that when you delete something it doesn't show... and if multiple rows or columns are deleted it doesn't show either. Otherwise no errors, so I'm happy so far :) thanks for your help.

Comment: @MattRidge: When you delete a value from the cell then it should show up in the log as `Blank` that is what this `If Len(Trim(Target.Value)) = 0` line does. Regarding the multiple range deletion, trapping that could be a problem as you are just storing One cell's value in `PreviousValue`

Comment: @SiddharthRout There is no way to set up a log system in where it will record multiple cells selected and deleted? Because if you get someone angry and just delete a swath of the document at one time, no log will ever exist that it happened.

Comment: For that what you need is Track Changes :) See this link http://superuser.com/questions/406248/track-changes-in-excel-2010

Comment: @SiddharthRout will this notify the other person that their changes have been recorded? What I'd like is a Track Changes script without notification... if that makes sense?

Comment: From personal experience Track Changes can be problematic especially over slow servers. If you really need to protect data across multiple users then have a secure master document and issue separate controlled versions. It's worth considering migrating to a more secure solution such as a properly managed database as Excel just doesn't cut-it managing valuable data.

Comment: Type `Track changes in a shared workbook` in Excel's help. Look for a section called `Ways to use change tracking` - Which talks about History tracking (Excel can display a separate history worksheet that provides a printable list of change details on which you can filter (filter: To display only the rows in a list that satisfy the conditions you specify. You use the AutoFilter command to display rows that match one or more specific values, calculated values, or conditions.) to find changes of interest. CONTD...

Comment: CONTD... The history worksheet is useful when a workbook has many changes or you want to investigate what occurred in a series of changes.) I am not too fond of shared workbooks but in this case it exactly does what you want....

Comment: If you have multiple users accessing 1 Excel workbook; forget about  track changes - nice in principle, fail in practice. It's not worth it!

Comment: @ooo: I know shared workbooks should be avoided but Track Changes failing on shared workbook is a new one for me... I must say... I have never come across a situation in the past where it failed considering a fact that we used to have a very "Heavy" use of it in the MIS department...

Comment: @Siddharth - try unpicking multiple changes to the same data when multiple users are all updating at the same time. Factor in users who like to keep the workbooks open all day. I agree it depends how the workbook has been setup and rules implemented but there's tools for a job and in this case Excel isn't it.

Comment: @Siddharth - I hope I don't sound like I'm arguing with you as you're right in everything you've said. Excel functions do work as intended sometimes. I'm just trying to get across that for valuable data Excel shouldn't be the sole solution. :)

Comment: @ooo: That's OK :) I never took it in that way. I am sure you must have come across those situations and hence you are voicing them out. I guess the OP is restricted very much to Excel and hence I am trying to give him solutions within the boundaries of Excel. If you notice that I did mention that Shared workbooks should be avoided but in this scenario where the user has to maintain a centralized log file, I feel VBA is not the right approach. In such a scenario the best approach is to use shared workbooks... :(

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.  Ideally you'd have a named range on the sheet being tracked which you could use to restrict tracking only to changes occuring inside that range.

```
Const MAX_TRACKED_CELLS As Long = 50
Dim PreviousValues As Object

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    Dim haveDict As Boolean, val, addr

    haveDict = Not PreviousValues Is Nothing

    If Target.Cells.Count <= MAX_TRACKED_CELLS Then
        For Each c In Target.Cells
            addr = c.Address()
            If haveDict Then
                If PreviousValues.exists(addr) Then
                    val = PreviousValues(addr)
                End If
            Else
                val = "{unknown}"
            End If

            If c.Value <> val Then
                Debug.Print "Changed:", addr, IIf(val = "", "Empty", val), _
                            " to ", IIf(c.Value = "", "Empty", c.Value)
            End If

        Next c
    End If


End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range

    If PreviousValues Is Nothing Then
        Set PreviousValues = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Else
        PreviousValues.RemoveAll
    End If

    If Target.Cells.Count <= MAX_TRACKED_CELLS Then
        For Each c In Target.Cells
            PreviousValues.Add c.Address(), c.Value
        Next c
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I've decided to go with both yours and Siddharth Rout's combined... thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: I'm trying your script outright, only a single question, what is Max_tracked_cells? there is no record of it anywhere...

Comment: It's a constant to avoid trying to track too many cells, and it's declared at the top of my posted code, so I'm not sure what you mean by "no record of it"? If (eg) a user inserts a column in Excel2007+, you don't want to start recording the contents of 1M+ cells into the dictionary. Ditto for row/column deletions. As I mentioned in the post, it's preferrable to set up a named range on the sheet being tracked, so you can use that to restrict the area on the sheet where logging is triggered (by intersecting `Target` with that range to give limit what you try to record).

Comment: Do a google search for Max_tracked_cells and there is only one page in google for it... that's all.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you (or me!) from declaring constants: in fact it's considered good practice to avoid ending up with "magic numbers" (and magic strings etc) in your code.

Comment: I mean that instead of using the literal number "50" in multiple places throughout your code it's better to declare a constant and then use the constant in the code. Then [months] later when you decide to change that to 100 you only have to change one line of code and not multiple lines (where inevitably you'll miss one...)