# Getting a Compile Error: Ambigiuous name detected: Worksheet_Selection change

Tags: excel, vba

Attached is the code I am using in my worksheet. This code up to the last bit work. the first line of the last code is where the error is... `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)` I'd like to know why, it seems to work with the other two subjects.

If anyone can help it be greatly appreciated.

```
Option Explicit

Dim PreviousValue

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim sLogFileName As String, nFileNum As Long, sLogMessage As String
    Dim NewVal

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    sLogFileName = ThisWorkbook.path & Application.PathSeparator & "Open Order Log.txt"

    If Not Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        If Target.Value <> PreviousValue Then
            If Len(Trim(Target.Value)) = 0 Then _
            NewVal = "Blank" Else NewVal = Target.Value

            sLogMessage = Now & Application.UserName & _
            " changed cell " & Target.Address & " from " & _
            PreviousValue & " to " & NewVal

            nFileNum = FreeFile
            Open sLogFileName For Append As #nFileNum
            Print #nFileNum, sLogMessage
            Close #nFileNum
        End If

    End If
LetsContinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    PreviousValue = Target(1).Value
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim sLogFileName As String
End Sub
    If FileLen(sLogFileName) > 3145728# Then
        sLogFileName = "Open Order Log - " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
        Name sLogFileName As "ThisWorkbook.path & Application.PathSeparator & \Temp\Open Order Log - " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you see my answer to your previous question?  It addresses tracking multiple cells in one edit.

Comment: Which question, I've asked multiple as of late.

Comment: Same code yesterday.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203020/i-have-a-code-to-log-usage-in-an-excel-sheet-but-i-get-one-bug-and-one-issue/12205874#12205874

Comment: I'm commenting now, thanks :)

Comment: You have two events named "Worksheet_SelectionChange" -- that's what "ambiguous name" is referring to.

Comment: @JimmyPena already solved below :) thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have closed `End Sub` after the `Dim sLogFileName As String`, which is wrong.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim sLogFileName As String
    If FileLen(sLogFileName) > 3145728# Then
        sLogFileName = "Open Order Log - " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
        Name sLogFileName As "ThisWorkbook.path & Application.PathSeparator & \Temp\Open Order Log - " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I have to ask, but why is it wrong? I'm self taught so I tend to miss the basics it seems in some cases... even though I seem to know a lot, I only know what I've done :)  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue, two Subs after the `End Sub` was removed by prior post with the same name...

```
Private Sub Size_Adjust(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim sLogFileName As String
    If FileLen(sLogFileName) > 3145728# Then
        sLogFileName = "Open Order Log - " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
        Name sLogFileName As "ThisWorkbook.path & Application.PathSeparator & \Temp\Open Order Log - " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the following code defined:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    PreviousValue = Target(1).Value
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim sLogFileName As String
    'other stuff
End Sub
```

You have two different subs *both* called `Worksheet_SelectionChange`. You need to determine which you want to use and rename/delete the other.